# What is this form of notation called?

Tags: physical-chemistry, notation

$$^{14}_6C \rightarrow ^{14}_7N + E^{-} + \bar{\nu}_e$$

Just curious!

Comment: Carbon 14 decays into Nitrogen 14, emits an electron and an electron anti-neutrino.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that the 14 is the total weight, not the neutrons.  I was viewing it as increasing by one proton, not converting a neutron to a proton.

Comment: Could be called "wrong" unless you have a $-1$ subscript on the electron  :)

Comment: If that is an electron it should be $e^-$. Capitalization is significant in the symbols for elements and particles, and electrons are lower-case.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the notation of [chemical equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_equation) adapted to nuclear reactions, accordingly sometimes called nuclear equations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a name for that notation! I would normally just describe it as a nuclear reaction, or perhaps as being written like a chemical reaction, but personally, I've never heard of a name for it.